# Effect of entries in /etc/securetty

Tags: security, login, pam

By default on RHEL 5.5 I have

```
[deuberger@saleen trunk]$ sudo cat /etc/securetty 
console
vc/1
vc/2
vc/3
vc/4
vc/5
vc/6
vc/7
vc/8
vc/9
vc/10
vc/11
tty1
tty2
tty3
tty4
tty5
tty6
tty7
tty8
tty9
tty10
tty11
```

What is the difference between each of the entry types (`console`, `vc/*`, and `tty*`)?  Specifically, what is the end result of adding and removing each entry type?

My understanding is that they affect how and when you can login, but are there any other effects?  And when can you and when can you not login depending on which entries are there?

**EDIT 1**

What I do know is that `tty1-6` correspond to whether you can login from the first 6 consoles that you reach using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>. I always thought those were virtual consoles, so I'm a bit confused.  And what does `console` correspond to?

Thanks.

**EDIT 2**

What is the effect, if any, in single user mode?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`/etc/securetty` is consulted by `pam_securetty` module to decide from which virtual terminals (`tty*`) `root` is allowed to login from.

In the past, `/etc/securetty` was consulted by programs like `login` directly, but now PAM handles that. So changes to `/etc/securetty` will affect anything using PAM with a configuration file that uses `pam_securetty.so`. So, only the `login` program is affected by default.

`/etc/pam.d/login` is used for local logins and `/etc/pam.d/remote` is used for remote logins (like telnet).

The primary entry types and their affects are as follows:

- If `/etc/securetty` doesn't exist, `root` is allowed to login from any `tty`
- If `/etc/securetty` exist and is empty, `root` access will be restricted to single user mode or programs that are not restricted by `pam_securetty` (i.e. `su`, `sudo`, `ssh`, `scp`, `sftp`)
- If you are using `devfs` (a deprecated filesystem for handling `/dev`), adding entries of the form `vc/[0-9]*` will permit root login from the given virtual console number.
- If you are using `udev` (for dynamic device management and replacement for `devfs`), adding entries of the form `tty[0-9]*` will permit root login from the given virtual console number.
- Listing `console` in `/etc/securetty` normally has no effect since `/dev/console` points to the current console and is normally only used as the `tty` filename in single user mode, which is unaffected by `/etc/securetty`
- Adding entries like `pts/[0-9]*` will allow programs that use pseudo-terminals (`pty`) and `pam_securetty` to login into `root` assuming the allocated `pty` is one of the ones listed; it's normally a good idea **not** to include these entries because it's a security risk; it would allow, for instance, someone to login into root via telnet, which sends passwords in plaintext (note that `pts/[0-9]*` is the format for `udev` which is used in RHEL 5.5; it will be different if using `devfs` or some other form of device management).

For single user mode, `/etc/securetty` is not consulted because the `sulogin` is used instead of `login` (see the `sulogin` man page for more info).  Also you can change the login program used in `/etc/inittab` for each runlevel.

Note that to you should not use `/etc/securetty` to control `root` logins via `ssh`.  To do that change the value of `PermitRootLogin` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  By default `/etc/pam.d/sshd` is not configured to consult `pam_securetty` (and therefore `/etc/securetty`).  You could add a line to do so, but `ssh` doesn't set the actual `tty` until sometime after the `auth` stage, so it doesn't work as expected. During the `auth` and `account` stages - at least for `openssh` - the `tty` (`PAM_TTY`) is hardcoded to `ssh`.

The above answer is based on RHEL 5.5.  Much of it will pertain to current distributions of other *nix systems, but there are differences, some of which I noted, but not all.

I answered this myself because the other answers were incomplete and/or inaccurate. Many other forums, blogs, etc online have inaccurate and incomplete information in this topic as well, so I've done extensive research and testing to try to get the correct details. If anything I've said is wrong, please let me know though.

Sources:

- http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-sec-network.html#s1-wstation-privileges
- http://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/local-doc/centos5/pam-0.99.6.2/html/sag-pam_securetty.html
- http://linux.die.net/man/1/login
- http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Text-Terminal-HOWTO/
- http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devices.txt
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_console
- http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/console.4.html
- http://www.unix.com/security/8527-restricting-root-login.html
- http://www.redhat.com/mirrors/LDP/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO-11.html#ss11.3
- http://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/local-doc/centos5/udev-095/udev_vs_devfs

Comment: +1 for taking the time to respond in such depth.  I'm not sure why there is no accepted answer here.  Seems like you've answered the OP's question.  I do like @Alexios comment, "vc/X and ttyX are synonym[ous]..."

Comment: Debian recently removed /etc/securetty.  It's considfered obsolete, and arguably more trouble than it's worth.  It was used for telnet and rlogin, but in order to get some container logins to work, pseudoterminals like "pts/0" are added on some systems, which defeats its original purpose.  If you need to restrict root login to a specific set of devices, there are more reliable mechanisms. See https://bugs.debian.org/731656

Answer (score 5):

`vc/X` and `ttyX` are synonyms: different paths to the same devices. The point of the redundancy is to catch various cases so as not to lock you out.

Traditionally, `login` (and possibly `getty`, I can't remember for sure) would check `/etc/securetty` and deny `root` logins on unlisted terminals. On modern systems, there are other ways to do this and other security measures too. Check out the contents of `/etc/login.defs` (which also covers `securetty`'s functionality and is recommended by the `securetty(5)` manpage), and also `/etc/pam.d/login`, where you can control the behaviour of this feature.

Since `securetty` is only checked by `login`, means of logging in that don't use `login` (e.g. SSH with `use_login=no`, X display managers, etc) aren't affected.

Comment: It's worth noting that on `busybox`-based systems it might still be of use for the simple fact that its `login` has no `/etc/login.defs` support.