# How to allow authentication with `sudo` using an alternate password?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, authentication

I have been given a long password by my company for my Ubuntu system. This password is cumbersome to enter when authenticating with `sudo` repeatedly.

Can I authenticate with `sudo` using a password other than the one associated with my user account, or enable `sudo` with no password authentication altogether?

Comment: you should probably rephrase your question to something: 'How to avoid entering p/w with sudo cmd'

Comment: This sounds like an [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it you're really trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could tie `sudo` authentication to the knowledge of a secret key managed by [`ssh-agent`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent). This can be achieved via [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_PAM) and the [`pam_ssh_agent_auth`](http://pamsshagentauth.sourceforge.net/) module. You can generate a separate keypair to use exclusively for `sudo` authentication. The password will be the passphrase used to encrypt the private key.

To configure the `pam_ssh_agent_auth` module add the following to `/etc/pam.d/sudo` *before* any other `auth` or `include` directives:

```
auth       sufficient pam_ssh_agent_auth.so file=/etc/security/authorized_keys
```

You will also need to tell `sudo` not to drop the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable by adding the following to `/etc/sudoers` (via `visudo`):

```
Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
```

Now add the public portion of the key you want to act as the authentication token to `/etc/security/authorized_keys`. You'd probably also want to add the `-t` switch to [`ssh-add`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh-add.1.html) with suitable short lifetime when adding the key to have `ssh-agent` mimic the default `sudo` behavior of prompting for password confirmation if a certain time has passed since it was last entered, or even use the `-c` switch to trigger password confirmation each time the key is used for authentication.

Note that the default in Ubuntu is to use [GNOME Keyring](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GnomeKeyring?action=show&redirect=GnomeKeyring) for SSH key management, which as far as I know [doesn't currently allow key timeout to be set](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/987167). You can disable SSH key management in GNOME Keyring completely by adding the following to `~/.config/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=SSH Key Agent
Comment=GNOME Keyring: SSH Agent
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=ssh
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;MATE;
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=Initialization
X-GNOME-AutoRestart=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-Notify=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-keyring
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.10.1
NoDisplay=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-keyring
```

which overrides `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop`, the key difference being the line:

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is feasible to enable the root account on your Ubuntu system, you can configure `sudo` to prompt for the root password instead of the password of the invoking user by adding the following to `/etc/sudoers` (using `visudo`):

```
Defaults rootpw
```

Ubuntu, by default, disables the root account by [locking out its password](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo). To enable it simply set a new password for `root`:

```
$ sudo passwd root
```

Even if you want to enable authentication with the root password for `sudo`, you can keep root logins disabled on local console devices by emptying (or commenting out) everything in [`/etc/securetty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/securetty.5.html). A blank /etc/securetty file, however, does *not* prevent the root user from logging in remotely using OpenSSH or other means that are not affected by [`pam_securetty.so`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_securetty) (e.g. `su`, `sudo`, `ssh`, `scp`, `sftp`). OpenSSH can be specifically configured to prevent root logins via the `PermitRootLogin no` stanza in`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but if you decide to do this you should make yourself aware of [any other effects](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41840/effect-of-entries-in-etc-securetty) that may be relevant in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just relax having to put the password in, by altering sudo's behavior, like so:

This was taken from the [ChromiumOS Tips and Tricks Page: Making Sudo A Little More Permissive](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/tips-and-tricks-for-chromium-os-developers#TOC-Making-sudo-a-little-more-permissive)

```
cd /tmp
cat > ./sudo_editor <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
echo Defaults \!tty_tickets > \$1          # Entering your password in one shell affects all shells 
echo Defaults timestamp_timeout=180 >> \$1 # Time between re-requesting your password, in minutes
EOF
chmod +x ./sudo_editor 
sudo EDITOR=./sudo_editor visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/relax_requirements
```

If you don't know what was done, `tty_tickets is now false`, meaning you don't need to authenticate on every tty.  `Timestamp_timeout is set to every 3 hours`, meaning that you input the password once every three hours.  Between the time you put it in, and the three hour limit, typing `sudo some command` will not result in being asked for your password until the limit expires.

`relax_requirement` can now be used to control sudo.  Available Options are in the [Sudoer's Manual](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudoers.man.html).  Look for the bolded section **SUDOERS OPTIONS**.  There are plenty of options besides the ones I described.  Doing it this way requires no modifications to PAM etc, and works on any system with or without PAM.

Answer (score 1):

*pam_ssh_agent_auth is overkill. It requires an agent.*

*This presumes sudo is already configured, and that configuration is not with NOPASSWD; you want a check, but a different check than login, be it randomized password or ssh key.*

HOW TO SET UP YOU OWN PASSWORD LIST FOR SUDO (on debian 12)

**sudo apt install libpam-pwdfile**

**nano /etc/pam.d/sudo**

```
%PAM-1.0
auth required pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile=/etc/security/sudo_passwd
#@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

**nano /etc/security/sudo_passwd**

```
yourusername:
```

**openssl passwd -6 >> /etc/security/sudo_passwd**

**nano /etc/security/sudo_passwd**

To see your shiny encrypted password after your user name - there should be no spaces in it!

Repeat as needed

Test sudo on a clean terminal - your password should work, but don't exit until you are sure it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the file `/etc/sudoers` with your editor of choice or just execute `visudo` and add the line to allow your specific user to use the `sudo` command without password. Something like:

> `user ALL = NOPASSWD : ALL`

Comment: Even better, but why not just a cron script to keep UIDs and GUIDs in sync between two users?

Comment: @Isaac You should __never__ edit `/etc/sudoers` without using `visudo`. `visudo` takes a number of precautions to avoid leaving the sudoers file in an inconsistent state, including locking the file against multiple simultaneous edits, providing basic sanity checks, and checking the file for parse errors before it is written to disk. Corrupting the sudoers file can potentially leave you stranded without administrator access, especially on Ubuntu where root logins are disabled by default. `visudo` honors the `EDITOR` environment variable if you want to use an editor other than Vi(m).

Comment: Also, `/etc/sudoers` is the global settings file.  User A does this to make it easier, but if User B can also sudo, this works for User B.  That may not be the intended behavior.

Comment: -1 for not knowing Thomas's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Keep an shell open, where you have used `sudo -i`, **the interactive mode**. Everytime you need to do something as root, do it inside this shell.

Then you could also re-run more then once needed commands by searching them via `[STRG] + R`, f.e. updating:

`aptitude update && aptitude upgrade && aptitude dist-upgrade`

If its reasonable or practical for your purposes, you could use a tty for this. Then it's easy to find, if you have a lot of programs running in *DM.